# C# Value of X changed after changing the list items

Tags: c#, list

I have this code, the elements in double[] X changed after changing the List1 items

```
    public class Class1
    {
        double[] C;
        double[][] pos;   
        public double S;
        double[] X;
        List<double[][]> List1 = new List<double[][]>();

        public Class1()
        {
        }

        public void runCode()
        {

            pos = new double[10][];
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
            {
                pos[ii] = new double[5];
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                    pos[ii][jj] = 0;
            }

            List1 = ListExtensions.ChunkBy(pos, 1);
            #region 
            X = new double[5];

            for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
            {
                X[jj] = 0.0;
            }

            S = 10000000000000000000;
            #endregion

            C = new double[List1[0].Length];
            for (int ii = 0; ii < List1[0].Length; ++ii)
            {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                    List1[0][ii][jj] = 1;


                if (C[ii] < S)
                {
                    X = List1[0][ii];
                }

            }
            //======================= Before
            for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                Console.WriteLine("----------------    " + X[jj]);


            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            for (int ii = 0; ii < List1[0].Length; ++ii)
               for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; jj++)
                   List1[0][ii][jj] = 5;

             Console.WriteLine("//======================= After");

            for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                Console.WriteLine("----------------    " + X[jj]);

            Console.Read();
        }  
    } // end class   
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------

```
public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static List<double[][]> ChunkBy(double[][] x, int number)
        {
            var result = new List<double[][]>();
            int chunkSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)x.GetLength(0)) / 
            number); 
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                result.Add(x.Skip(chunkSize * i).Take(chunkSize).ToArray());
            }

            return result;
         }
    }
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Class1 test = new Class1();
           test.runCode();
}
```

The value of X must be changed in this part only:

```
 if (C[ii] < S)
 {
    X = List1[0][ii];
 }
```

**Output:**

----------------    1

----------------    1

----------------    1

----------------    1

----------------    1

//======================= After

----------------    5

----------------    5

----------------    5

----------------    5

----------------    5

The elements in double[] X after for loop, should be 1 not 5

Comment: The value of `X` can neither be `1` or `5`, `X` is a `double[]`, it's an array, not a scalar value. I don't understand the question.

Comment: And the values in the arrays _referenced_ by `X` are changed a lot of times in your code. Note that `X` is a _reference_ to an array. If you say `X = List[0][0];` now `X` points to the array in `List[0][0]`, it's _not_ a copy.

Comment: @René Vogt  what I should change in the code?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to achieve. Unfortunately, neither your variable names, nor your method names, nor your problem description helps to understand what this code should do. So I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: `List<double[][]> List = new List<double[][]>();` `List` is a reserved word / Type in .NET don't name your variables the same name of the Type, give it a more meaningful name also .. learn to use the debugger

Comment: @RenéVogt, I think I solved the problem. I did this:

**List[0][ii].CopyTo(X, 0);**

instead of 

X = List[0][0];

Comment: @MethodMan, I have changed the names here, I am using another names in my code, I cannot share the code with the original names.

Comment: @Shdotcom LOL yes you can.. what you wrote would mean nothing to the outside world anyway.. start using the debugger..

Comment: @MethodMan, it means.

Comment: what is the reason of down voting ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **List1[0][ii].CopyTo(X, 0); instead of X = List[0][ii];`**

to make a copy of List1[0][ii] and save it in double[] X

```
 public class Class1
    {
        double[] C;
        double[][] pos;   
        public double S;
        double[] X;
        List<double[][]> List1 = new List<double[][]>();

        public Class1()
        {
        }

        public void runCode()
        {

            pos = new double[10][];
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
            {
                pos[ii] = new double[5];
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                    pos[ii][jj] = 0;
            }

            List1 = ListExtensions.ChunkBy(pos, 1);
            #region 
            X = new double[5];

            for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
            {
                X[jj] = 0.0;
            }

            S = 10000000000000000000;
            #endregion

            C = new double[List1[0].Length];
            for (int ii = 0; ii < List1[0].Length; ++ii)
            {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                    List1[0][ii][jj] = 1;


                if (C[ii] < S)
                {
                    List1[0][ii].CopyTo(X, 0);
                }

            }
            //======================= Before
            for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                Console.WriteLine("----------------    " + X[jj]);


            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            for (int ii = 0; ii < List1[0].Length; ++ii)
               for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; jj++)
                   List1[0][ii][jj] = 5;

             Console.WriteLine("//======================= After");

            for (int jj = 0; jj < 5; ++jj)
                Console.WriteLine("----------------    " + X[jj]);

            Console.Read();
        }  
    } // end class   
}
```